# Java actionlistener actionPerformed in different class

Tags: java, class, actionlistener

I have two classes: the main one and one called "Window".
There are some buttons in the Window class, is it possible to let the "main" class know what happened? In short, buttons in class "Window" should trigger some stuff in the main class.

Or should I just type everything in the "Window" class?

Comment: Do you want to notify the whole class? As in with `static` fields? (Don't do this) Instead, have your `Window` object create a `Main` object and operate on it.

Comment: But won't it be the same as just doing everything in the Window class?

Comment: Yeah, all code can be written in the same file, but that is not good design. [Check out the High Cohesion GRASP pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#High_Cohesion)

Comment: That's how the original problem occured, by me trying to create a well-designed program.

Comment: It's not a problem, it's a solution. [Go through this tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. `ActionListener` is interface,so you can let "main" class implement this interface and pass it to Window class as parameter in Windows class constructor.
Following code snippet that can help you:

Main class:

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //button clicked, so do you job here

    }
}
```

Windows class:

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Window extends JPanel
{
    public Window(ActionListener listener)
    {
        JButton b = new JButton("Button 1");
        b.addActionListener(listener);
        add(b);

        //do other stuff
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Window w = new Window(new Main());
        //continue with initialization process
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Although my main method is in the class Main so I passed "this" to "window" consturctor :)