# ActionListener in parent class

Tags: java, actionlistener, parent

I am struggling with the ActionListener in Java in a parent class, I tried a bunch of possible solutions but could not get it work. This here also did not help:
[Java actionlistener actionPerformed in different class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407038/java-actionlistener-actionperformed-in-different-class)

The problem is as follows:

Class2 **extends** Class1, I have a button in Class2. As soon as the button in Class2 is pressed, Class1 should be notified through action listener and perform the event.

I'm struggling to let Class1 know that the event has happened. It looked pretty simple to me, but nevertheless I'm struggling.

Your help will be much apprechiated, thank you!

Parent Class

```
package test;

//imports removed for better visibility

public class ParentClass extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

JFrame frame;

public void createParentGui() {
    frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JPanel mainCard = new JPanel(new CardLayout(20, 20));
    ChildClass card1 = new ChildClass();
    mainCard.add(card1);

    frame.add(mainCard, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    System.out.println("Button pressed, action!");

}
}
```

Child Class

```
package test;

//imports removed for better visibility

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

ActionListener listener = null; //this is probably not right, how to do 
//with a local variable when passing it to the parent class?

public Child() {
    createGui();
}

private void createGui() {

    final JButton b = new JButton("press me");
    b.addActionListener(listener);
    add(b);
}
}
```

Comment: if `Class2`  knows that an action is performed `Class1` should know aswell, as `Class2` is a `Class1`. In Order for us to help you should probably include your code

Comment: I think you should rather do some reading on the java basics. Like understanding what it means that an **object** is of Class2. And then: provide code please; as of now, there is no chance we could help with such input. Thus: put up  [mcve] ....

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have added example code which shows the problem.

Comment: I fail to understand why ChildClass extends ParentClass. There doesn't seem to be an *is a* relationship between the classes. But anyway, you want `addActionListener(this)`.

Comment: @JBNizet
There will be more child classes and and all will do some GUI stuff, hence I thought it might be worth to have a parent class for all the GUI stuff. Would you rather do it all in separate classes? If so, why? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ChildClass` has all of the fields and methods that `ParentClass` does (in addition to its own unique fields and methods).  This is how inheritance works.

So, since `ParentClass` is an `ActionListener`, that means that `ChildClass` is too.  More specifically, `ChildClass` has *inherited* the `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method of `ParentClass`.

**Therefore, change `b.addActionListener(listener);` to `b.addActionListener(this)`.**  *(you can also remove the `listener` field of `ChildClass`)*

The new code will pass "this" `ChildClass` object to `b`, which will then call `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` whenever the button is pressed.  And since any `ChildClass` object has the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` of `ParentClass`, that means that `ParentClass#actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` will be called (as you intended).

Comment: Thanks Travis, that worked! And thanks also for the detailed explanation, it refreshed my inheritance classes-stuff.